# Audio level while recording in silverlight 5

Tags: c#, silverlight, audio, naudio, speech

Hi I am recording `PCM audio` in a web application using **silverlight 5** and I wanted to know is there any way that we can show the audio level like how we do on `NAUDIO`.

I am not able to use `Naudio with silverlight`. This is so that the user knows that his voice is actually being captured by the system.

Answer (score 0):

You would use the same technique. Assuming you are recording in 16 bit, every 2 bytes should be converted to a short (you can use the BitConverter.ToInt16 class) and then look for the maximum sample value over a short period (say 100ms), and use that to set the value on your volume meter control. For the volume meter, a styled progress bar is often a good approach. See my [blog post here](http://mark-dot-net.blogspot.co.uk/2009/09/styling-wpf-volume-meter.html) for an example.